# Selenium iterating through list C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to create a simple loop that iterates through a list and searches for a specific text. When the text is found it should scroll down to that option so it's visible and then click on it. I came up with something like this but it's in java and i need the code in c#, can any one help me with the syntax since i'm just learning c#

```
  public static IWebElement FindListItem(IWebElement listContainer, string itemText)
{
    List<IWebElement> allOptions = listContainer.FindElements(By.XPath(""));
    for (WebElement we: allOptions)
    {
        listContainer.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN); 
        sleep(250);
        if (we.getText().contains(text)) select.selectByVisibleText("Value1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try,

```
public static IWebElement FindListItem(IWebElement listContainer, string itemText)
    {

        List<IWebElement> allOptions = listContainer.FindElements(By.XPath("")).ToList();
        foreach (var webElement in allOptions)
        {
            listContainer.SendKeys(Keys.Down);
           Thread.Sleep(250);
            if (webElement.Text.Contains(itemText))
                select.selectByVisibleText("Value1");
        }
    }
```

Comment: .getText is underlined with an message "IWebElement does not contain a definition for 'getText' and no extension method 'getText' accepting a first argument of type 'IWebElement'  could be found" 

any ideas how could i fix that?

Comment: Please try webElement.Text and let me know.

Comment: Non-invocable member 'IWebElemnent.Text' cannot be used like a method

Comment: I have edit after tried in my machine. Please try the edited code. I don't know what is 'select' in your code though. I assume you have have a type for 'select'. Please don't forgot to add all needed Namespace though

Comment: Cool. Can you please accept the answer and vote up so that it would be helpful for other in the community :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
public static void FindListItem(SelectElement select, string itemText) 
{
 var options = select.Options();
 if (options.Any(o => o.Text.Contains(itemText)) 
 {
  select.SelectByIndex(options.IndexOf(options.First(o => o.Text.Contains(itemText))));
 }
}
```

That will check if there is an option that contains the item text and if it does then it will select the index of said element.

Sorry if there any mistakes I am doing this from my phone.

I hope it helps.